# Trigger action after user is created in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In a Wordpress site I need to create a custom post every time a user is created. In this post I will have an administrator adding private files to the user. I need to trigger a function that inserts a custom post after the user is created. This is the function:

```
function user_after_creation( $user_id ){
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    $post_setup = array(
        'post_type'     => 'private_user_page',
        'post_title'    => $user->user_login,
        'post_name'     => $user->user_login,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_excerpt'  => ''
    );
    wp_insert_post( $post_setup );
}
```

Well, I was thinking of something like this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'user_after_creation', 10, 1 );
```

to trigger the action, someone else suggested:

```
do_action( 'user_register', user_after_creation( $wpdb->insert_id ) );
```

But i am not really sure of what to do.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`user_register`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register). It is called when a user account in first registered/created and passes the user id. Should meet your needs.